# T-SQL Add Counter to Grouped Data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to produce a query that displays a column which increments (counts) for each group set of data. The overall order of the results does not matter, except the occurrence must count by date (oldest = 1) and should reset for each set of grouped data. Here is an example table, ProductInteractions.

```
+---------+------------+----------------+------------+
| User ID | Product ID | Date Purchased | Occurrence |
+---------+------------+----------------+------------+
| user15  | b1290      | 1/1/2012       |          1 |
| user15  | b1290      | 1/15/2013      |          2 |
| user15  | b1290      | 3/15/2019      |          3 |
| user15  | a7983      | 7/22/2017      |          1 |
| user2   | a7983      | 12/3/2015      |          1 |
| user2   | a7983      | 5/6/2016       |          2 |
| user3   | a7983      | 3/24/2017      |          1 |
+---------+------------+----------------+------------+
```

Original data:

```
+---------+------------+-----------+
| User ID | Product ID |   Date    |
+---------+------------+-----------+
| user15  | b1290      | 1/1/2012  |
| user2   | a7983      | 5/6/2016  |
| user15  | b1290      | 3/15/2019 |
| user15  | a7983      | 7/22/2017 |
| user2   | a7983      | 12/3/2015 |
| user15  | b1290      | 1/15/2013 |
| user3   | a7983      | 3/24/2017 |
+---------+------------+-----------+
```

Note in the example above, user15 and product b1290 have 3 interactions. It is important that the first occurrence is tied to the initial interaction date and that subsequent interactions are counted by increasing date.

I believe that the basic format of the query will be:

```
    SELECT [User ID],
           [Product ID],
           [Date Purchased]
           -- Something here utilizing IDENTITY, maybe?
      FROM ProductInteractions
     GROUP BY [User ID],
              [Product ID];
```

Comment: Do you know about ROW_NUMBER()?

Comment: I didn't, but I do now. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use **ROW_NUMBER()**

Here is the code to test/validate teh script below: replace ProductInteractions by your own table

```
declare @ProductInteractions as table([User ID] varchar(50),[Product ID] varchar(50),[Date] datetime)
insert into @ProductInteractions values
('user15'  , 'b1290'      , '1/1/2012'  ),
('user2'   , 'a7983'      , '5/6/2016'  ),
('user15'  , 'b1290'      , '3/15/2019' ),
('user15'  , 'a7983'      , '7/22/2017' ),
('user2'   , 'a7983'      , '12/3/2015' ),
('user15'  , 'b1290'      , '1/15/2013' ),
('user3'   , 'a7983'      , '3/24/2017' )

select [User ID],[Product ID],[Date],
row_number() over(partition by [User ID],[Product ID] order by [date]) [occurence]
from @ProductInteractions order by [Product ID] desc
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Thanks! I really appreciate the screenshots.

Answer (score 3):

A simple [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is perfect for this.

```
SELECT [User ID],
    [Product ID],
    [Date Purchased]
    , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [User ID], [Product ID] order by [Date Purchased])
FROM ProductInteractions
GROUP BY [User ID],
        [Product ID];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am going to have to practice up with this one. Definitely helpful in my day-to-day.